# how to get the network gateway address in Qt?

Tags: linux, qt, gateway

how to get the network gateway address in Qt?(linux)

I'm trying to get the gateway using the standard Qt library. I'm playing with QHostAddress, QNetworkInterface and so on but I cannot extract the gateway.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Qt is generally C++, but which version of Qt?  I don't see anything new in Qt5 that helps past the thread Ruslan gives.  Often you can use the subnet and then use either *x.x.x.1* or *x.x.x.254*; the configured interface route is a better way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have parsed the `route -n` command to get the default gateway.

Answer (score 2):

It is not implemented in Qt.

http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/7497

There is you can find solutions for windows and linux in comments

Answer (score 1):

On Linux and Android read  /proc/net/route e.g.

```
QFile file("/proc/net/route");
QByteArray content = file.readAll();
file.close();
```

Comment: File still needs to be opened